# PHP/Javascript security

Tags: php, security, apache, request

I have 1 JavaScript file that will post messages on Facebook. I can call this file using

`{'message': 'This is a message'}`

as POST parameters and it will publish it on Facebook.
It's location is `/request/facebook.php`. Now I thought about this. Anyone can call this file and post messages on my Facebook account! How can I protect this file, so it can only be called from a few servers? I know their IP addresses. And how can I call it then from my own server (without the loss of security)?

Comment: Password protect it, use Apache to restrict the IPs that can access it, etc... Not really a programming question, should be on webmasters SO.

Comment: only be called from a few servers!!!

Comment: http://www.teachmejoomla.net/code/php/remote-ip-detection-with-php.html

Comment: @kevin -- whats the URL of the site? ^_^

Answer (score 2):

IP restriction is a good start, but IP's change every once in awhile.

I would consider using a username/password or some sort. It doesn't need to be overly complex, as long as the transmission of the key/password is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some sort of security on your site, to prevent just anyone from invoking your server script.  IP restriction is certainly viable.